# How to make a Three column page with two fixed side columns

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this site for a while now, trying to make things work for me, but to no avail. What I want to do is to make a three column site, with the two end columns being fixed. But the center div should scroll based on whether the contents overflow its height or not.
Bellow is the HTML

```
<div id="main_body">
        <div id="accord_menu">
           Left Navigation Accordion
        </div>              
        <div id="col_two">
            There is no knowledge that is not power
        </div>
        <div id="col_three">
           <div id="inner">
               Here is  the right navigation
           </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear"/>
    </div>
```

And Here is the CSS I have used so far:

```
#accord_menu{
            height: auto;
            width: 150px;
            position:fixed;
            margin-left:3px;
            margin-top: 53px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        #col_two{
            width: 600px;
            height: 1000px;
            border: 1px solid #AAA;
            background: #E6E6FA;   
            position:relative;

        }
        #col_three{
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
            max-height: 92px;
            min-height: 91%;
            position:fixed;
            margin-left:900px
            margin-top: 53px;
            background: #E6E6FA;
        }
```

When I resize the browser, the fixed contents disappear, especially the right one, and there would be no horizontal scroll for it. I have also tried placing the fixed ones in a `div` that is positioned relatively, still the contents start moving around when the browser is resized and flows over the center div `(col_two)`. I would really appreciate all help on this. Thanks.

Comment: So ? Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope, what I want is the facebook king of fixed columns, but then I realise that JavaScript might be what I need

Comment: Explain. What about our answer does not accomplish this? What would scripts provide for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to answer since there are so many down votes going on here... [HERE is a working example:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ahmMf/) I hope this is what you were going for.

HTML

```
<aside class="global-nav-w">
   <nav class="global-nav">
       Left - 
   </nav>
</aside>

<section class="main-content cf">
    Main content
</section>

<aside class="sidebar">
   <nav class="sub-nav">
       Right
   </nav>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Google box sizing - this should be default for any person writing CSS as of 2013 */

/* Google micro clear fix to clear floats without the extra <br /> */
.cf:before,
.cf:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }

html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.global-nav-w, .main-content, .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
} /* stack them for mobile ? */

.global-nav-w {    
    background-color: red;
}

.main-content {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: lightblue;
}


@media (min-width: 50em) { /* ========= */

    .global-nav-w {
        position: fixed;
        width: 15em;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        height: 100%; /*?*/
    }

    .main-content {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 15em;
        padding-right: 15em;
        height: 100%; /*?*/

        min-height: 100em; /* to show scrolling */
    }

    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 15em;
        top: 0; right: 0;
        height: 100%; /*?*/
    }

} /* ===END @MEDIA RULE ETC ============== */
```

Comment: Watch out with fixed position in general. I was just at best buy playing with the larger desktop tablet things. Fixed stuff was pretty buggy on the lenovo, windows and HP machines. It can be done somehow... but not just with regular fixed. I'm currently trying to figure out how to get some fixed stuff working.. but I can't trust in in production yet. Sucks!

Answer (score -1):

In your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside id='left'>left</aside>
        <section id='main'>main</section>
        <aside id='right'>right</aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this css:

```
aside, section { padding: 2%; }
aside { width: 21%; background-color: #eee; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
section { width: 46%; background-color: #ddd; }
aside#left { position: fixed; }
aside#right { position: fixed; right: 0; }
section#main { position: absolute; left: 25%; right: 25%; }
```

Will produce your desired effect.

EDIT: Removed the `float: left;` from the `aside, section` not that it matters as it was working. Because the `position: fixed` and `absolute` **will** override the floating behavior.

Comment: You cant add float to an element as well as positioning